# Using DISTINCT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, adventureworks

In AdventureWorks2012 database, I have to use the `Sales.SalesPerson`, `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`, `Sales.SalesOrderDeatil`, and `Production.Product` tables listing all Distinct products that have `ProductID` and Name which are sold in Territory 5.

Below is my attempted answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sod.ProductID,
    p.Name 
FROM
    Sales.SalesPerson SP,
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH,
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD,
    Production.Product P 
WHERE
    SP.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesOrderID AND
    soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID AND
    sod.SalesOrderID = p.ProductID
```

The query executed successfully, but 0 rows were affected.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your joins are on the wrong fields, particularly the first and third conditions.  Also, learn proper join syntax (the `join` keyword) rather than doing implicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
sod.SalesOrderID = p.ProductID
```

i'm guessing this, orderid = productid? probably mistake, maybe you wanted

```
sod.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: No, I still have "0 rows affected"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SOD.ProductID,
    P.Name AS ProductName
FROM
    Sales.SalesPerson SP,
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH,
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD,
    Production.Product P 
WHERE
    SP.BusinessEntityID = SOH.BusinessEntityID AND
    SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID AND
    SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID AND
    SOH.TerritoryID = 5;
```

Comment: Didn't Work.  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'BusinessEntityID'.

Comment: If you get an error like invalid column name, then you need to check your database tables to see what the columns are called. In this case you are trying to find the link between the SalesOrderHeader table and the SalesPerson table. I don't have AdventureWorks2012, but on an older version, these columns are called SalesPersonID